# About calling when there is a function in the method

Tags: python

I wrote the following code.

The code ran without problems and was printed as "test".

**test1.py**

```
class testClass:
    def test(self):
        def test_test():
            print("test")
        return test_test

f = testClass().test()
f()
```

However, if I rewrite the code as follows, it will not work with an error.

**test2.py**

```
class testClass:
    def test(self):
        def test_test():
            print("test")
        return test_test

    def printTest(self):
        self.test()

f = testClass().printTest()
f()
```

What should I do now?

Comment: I think you are getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` error. It is because  you must return the result from `printTest` method(`return self.test()`). otherwise it will implicitly return `None`

Comment: Oh, that's it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In second case you're not returning anything from `printTest`. A simple

```
def printTest(self):
    return self.test()
```

will do the trick.